# ADX 1 minute intervals

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have ADX table which contains some Statuses with Timestamps like this:

[image]

I wanted to generate 1 minute interval data to show status for each minute like this:

[image]

I'm just starting with KQL but I see that I'm not able to do a join with the between condition (as if I did it using TSQL):

[image]

Is there any simple trick to optimally implement this scenario?

I tried different joining possibilities, using UNION operators and so on

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to share your code, RithwikBojja. Just like this:

```
 let MainTable = datatable(Date: datetime)
[ 
    datetime(2022-04-01),
    datetime(2023-04-02),
    datetime(2023-05-01),
    datetime(2023-07-02)
];
```

That is is the only chance to reproduce what you are doing. Currently you are providing just an image, and probably nobody wants to retype what he sees.